# Rails using 'where' on a model that has a has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, activemodel

I have 2 models, `Account` and `User`

```rb
class Account
  has_many :users
end

class User
  belongs_to :account
end
```

The relevant model details for my issue are:

- Every Account has a `subscription` type, which can be either `standard`, `premium` or `enterprise`

How do I properly list all `Users` that belong to a `premium` Account? Additionally, how do I list all Users in *all* `premium` Accounts, since there can be any number of `premium` Accounts.

I've tried several variations of the things below:

```rb
Account.where(subscription: "premium").users # undefined method users

User.where(subscription: "premium") # returns nothing

Account.where(subscription: "premium").each do |account|
  account.users # seems to return an array?
end
```

Comment: Please refrain from asking multiple questions in one - instead create a seperate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question:

> list all Users that belong to a premium Account:

Your first try (`Account.where(subscription: "premium").users`) doesn't work because `Account.where(subscription: "premium")` already returns many Accounts, so a list (more precisely an ActiveRecord Relation object) and you can't call `.users` on that list. You can only call `.users` on one account
What you need is a `join` statement to join both tables. You can read more about it here: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables
And since you want users, you should start with user.

Your query should look something like that:

```
User.joins(:account).where(accounts: {subscription: "premium"})
```

This will give you all Users that have an account with the subscirption type premium.

I think your second question regarding the query is acutally the same

> Additionally, how do I list all Users in all premium Accounts, since there can be any number of premium Accounts.

Answer (score 3):

What you want is a left inner join:

```
User.joins(:account)
    .where(accounts: { subscription: "premium" })
```

This will return any records from the users table that have a match in the joined table.

> How do I properly list all Users that belong to a premium Account?

If what you mean is users that belong to a specific account you would call the `#users` method on that specific account.

```
account = Account.eager_load(:users).find(1)
account.users
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are great, another option would be in `Account` model

```
scope :premium, -> { where(subscription: 'premium') }
```

and your query

```
User.joins(:account).merge(Account.premium)
```